# javascript make html table dynamically from json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have ***json*** data like this, form a *HTML* table with dynamic headings. Leave empty item in that box if there is no value.

```
[
    {
        "name":"value1",
        "email":"user1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id":"123",
        "name":"value2",
    },
    {
        "name":"value3",
        "email":"user3@gmail.com",
        "messsage":"lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
        "name":"value4",
        "email":"user4@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

[example table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c56Uu.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example on how to accept an array of arbitrary objects and just render them on a table by inspecting all of their properties.

Maybe this is an answer trying to address a problem bigger than what was strictly asked anyway it could be interesting to inspect this option.

The main issue with this solution is that, since there's no guarantee on the fact that all objects in the array will be consistent with their properties, the very first step is navigating the whole array collecting a set of unique property names found and use it to build the table header.

Such array of unique property names will be used also later to build the table rows. Since the list of objects doesn't hold the order of the property names, they will be listed randomly in the output table.

The way header and rows get built from the `propertyNames` and `data` goes like this:

```
const header = buildTableHeader(uniquePropertyNames);
const rows = buildTableBody(uniquePropertyNames, data);
```

The order of items in the `uniquePropertyNames` will rule how they will be rendered on the output table.

The entry point is just:

```
renderObjectsToTable(data, '#target');
```

Where `'#target'` is the selector to fetch the target table to render the data inside.

***Edit:***
I corrected a mistake I did using the variable `data` inside a function and I added the demo option to pass a list of html elements to the rendering procedure. Just to draw a bigger picture.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "value1",
    "email": "user1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "value2",
  },
  {
    "name": "value3",
    "email": "user3@gmail.com",
    "messsage": "lorem ipsum"
  },
  {
    "name": "value4",
    "email": "user4@gmail.com"
  }
];

renderObjectsToTable(data, '#target');
  
function renderObjectsToTable(objects, target){

  const uniquePropertyNames = [];
  objects.forEach(obj => {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      if(!uniquePropertyNames.includes(prop))
        uniquePropertyNames.push(prop);
    }
  });

  const header = buildTableHeader(uniquePropertyNames);
  const rows = buildTableBody(uniquePropertyNames, objects);

  const table = document.querySelector(target);
  table.querySelector('thead').append(header);
  table.querySelector('tbody').append(...rows);
}


function buildTableHeader(propertyNames){
  const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
  propertyNames.forEach( prop => {
    const headerCell = document.createElement('th');
    headerCell.innerText = prop;
    headerRow.append(headerCell);
  });
  return headerRow;
}

function buildTableBody(propertyNames, objects){
  const tableRows = [];
  objects.forEach(obj => {
    debugger;
    const currentRow = document.createElement('tr');
    propertyNames.forEach(prop => {
      const tableCell = document.createElement('td');
      debugger;
      const value = (obj[prop] === undefined) ? '' : obj[prop];
      tableCell.innerText = value;
      currentRow.append(tableCell);
    });
    tableRows.push(currentRow);
  });
  return tableRows;
}

function goWild(){
  document.querySelector('#target thead').innerHTML = '';
  document.querySelector('#target tbody').innerHTML = '';
  const nodes = document.getElementById('wildList').childNodes;
  renderObjectsToTable(nodes, '#target');
}
```

```css
#target{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#target th,
#target td
{
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: .2em;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

#gowild{
  padding: .5em 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="target">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button id="gowild" onclick="goWild();">GO WILD</button>

<ul id="wildList" class="hidden">
  <li data-wild="very">Wild List Item #1</li>
  <li data-wild="toomuch">Wild List Item #2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "value1",
    "email": "user1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "value2",
  },
  {
    "name": "value3",
    "email": "user3@gmail.com",
    "messsage": "lorem ipsum"
  },
  {
    "name": "value4",
    "email": "user4@gmail.com"
  }
];

const tableBody = document.querySelector("tbody");
data.forEach(d => {
  tableBody.innerHTML += `<tr>
                    <td>${d.id || ""}</td>
                    <td>${d.name || ""}</td>
                    <td>${d.email || ""}</td>
                    <td>${d.messsage || ""}</td>
                </tr>`;
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table :where(tr, th, td) {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>message</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        const json = [
            {
                "angelo": "pinky",
                "pinky": "pinky",
                "id": "1234",
                "Last name": "value1",
                "email": "user1@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "123",
                "name": "value2",
            },
            {
                "name": "value3",
                "email": "user3@gmail.com",
                "messsage": "lorem ipsum"
            },
            {
                "name": "value4",
                "email": "user4@gmail.com"
            }
        ];
        const json2 = [
            {
                "pinky": "pinky",
                "id": "1234",
                "Last name": "value1",
                "email": "user1@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "123",
                "name": "value2",
            },
            {
                "name": "value3",
                "email": "user3@gmail.com",
                "messsage": "lorem ipsum"
            },
            {
                "name": "value4",
                "email": "user4@gmail.com"
            }
        ];
        addTable(json);
        addTable(json2);
    });


    function addTable(json) {
        var _headers = [];
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
        table.border = '1';

        var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
        var tableHeader = document.createElement('THEAD');
        table.appendChild(tableHeader);
        table.appendChild(tableBody);

        json.forEach(function (obj) {
            for (let key in obj) {
                if (_headers.find(elementKey => elementKey == key)) { }
                else _headers.push(key);
            }
        });

        for (let index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
            var _item = json[index];
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);

            _headers.forEach(function (key) {

                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_item[key] != null ? _item[key] : ''));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            })

        }

        _headers.forEach(function (header) {

            var th = document.createElement('TH');
            th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(header));

            tableHeader.appendChild(th);

        })

        body.appendChild(table);
    }
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```